# How to save data into JsonObject field in Baqend?

Tags: angularjs, baqend

I have a field type JsonObject in Baqend. How can I save data with it's SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the field to your JsonObject.
For example:

```
let obj = new DB.Test();
obj.json = { "foo": "bar" };
obj.save();
```